# How do I multiply two values in dictionary Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
{'A': {5.0, 6.20}, 'B': {1.92, 3.35}, 'C': {3.21, 7.0}, 'D': {2.18, 9.90}}
```

I want to do an operation by where,i.e., if there's a key match, let's say on `A`, then I would multiply 5.0 and 6.20 and return that value.

Comment: What's the problem with using a dictionary lookup `d['A']`?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using sets instead of lists or tuples for the values?

Comment: I fixed that and made it into a list. Thanks for pointing out. I had a d'oh moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`operator.mul(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul) like the below:

```
from operator import mul

def mul_val(dct, key):
    # When a key does not exist, return 0*0, you can change it to what you want
    return mul(*dct.get(key, [0.0,0.0]))

dct = {'A': {5.0, 6.20}, 'B': {1.92, 3.35}, 'C': {3.21, 7.0}, 'D': {2.18, 9.90}}
print(mul_val(dct, 'A'))
```

Output:

```
31.0
```

Update base this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74932424/how-do-i-multiply-two-values-in-dictionary-python/74932476#comment132233933_74932424):

```
from operator import mul

list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
list2 = [5.0, 1.92, 3.21, 2.18]
list3 = [6.2, 3.35, 7.0, 9.0]

# Option_1
output_1 = {x: y*z  for x, y, z in zip(list1, list2, list3)}

# Option_2
output_2 = {x: mul(*y) for x, *y in zip(list1, list2, list3)}

print(output_1)
# {'A': 31.0, 'B': 6.4319999999999995, 'C': 22.47, 'D': 19.62}

print(output_2)
# {'A': 31.0, 'B': 6.4319999999999995, 'C': 22.47, 'D': 19.62}
```